# Assembly Programs Not Compiling in x86 Build Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

so I'm trying to learn MASM, and I've looked online but I can't get it to compile in an x86 Build. I have a simple .asm file that just has

```
end
```

then a c file with main.

When I set VS with a x64 Build it compiles successfully with ml64; however, when I use x86 I get:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(50,5):
>   error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\test.obj"
>   /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Tatest.asm" exited with code 1.

Comment: Check to see if it produced a log file with the actual error from ML.EXE. ML64.EXE only supports one model type, but ML.EXE supports multiple model types, so you may possibly need a processor type like `.586p`, and probably need a `.model FLAT` directive in the .asm file for 32 bit build.

Comment: yeah. i just fixed it. i needed that + it seems like my command prompt environment variables which were set up with vcvarsall.bat x64, got exported to VS. I just launched it with the icon and it worked.